# Correct Oracle Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have table A with below records:

Table A

```
+----+-----+
|Tuid|Etuid|
+----+-----+
|d1  |E1   |
+----+-----+
|d2  |E1   |
+----+-----+
|d3  |E2   |
+----+-----+
|d4  |E3   |
+----+-----+
|d5  |E4   |
+----+-----+
```

Table B

```
+----+---+
|Tuid|FID|
+----+---+
|d1  |1  |
+----+---+
|d2  |2  |
+----+---+
|d3  |1  |
+----+---+
|d3  |2  |
+----+---+
|d4  |1  |
+----+---+
|d4  |2  |
+----+---+
|d5  |1  |
+----+---+
|d5  |3  |
+----+---+
```

Here Tuid od Table A and Tuid of Table B are related. I want to query all the records which are having 1 and 2 FIDs in the same Etuid. I am expecting E1, E2 and E3 in result. I should not get E4 as it contains only '1' FID and not '2'.

I have written query like this:

```
SELECT TableA.ETuid
FROM TableA 
WHERE TableA.Tuid IN (
    SELECT TableB.Tuid
    FROM TableB
    WHERE TableB.FID IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY TableB.Tuid
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

This is giving only E2 and E3 in result, please help me to get E1 also in result.

Comment: you don't have two records for d1 and d2 in TableB that may be the problem

Comment: Yes thts correct this is expected data in DB and I still want 'E1' in the result, I am asking help to modify query so that I can get E1, E2 and E3 in result.

Comment: try this count(*) >=1

Comment: If I do count(*) >=1, it gives E4 as well which I dont want as E4 doesnot contain FID=2

Comment: change the condition to WHERE TableB.FID IN (1, 2) and TableB.FID not in (3)

Comment: I do not have information which FIDs to exclude while forming query. There could be N no of FIDs like '3' which I do not want in result Etuid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (not tested)

```
select a.ETuid
  from tablea a
  join tableb b on (a.ETuid= b.ETuid)
 where b.fid in (1,2)
 group by a.ETuid
 having count(distinct b.fid) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an elegant solution, but the logic is pretty straight forward:

```sql
SELECT a1.Etuid
  FROM TableA a1
  INNER JOIN TableB b1 ON (a1.Tuid=b1.Tuid)
  WHERE b1.FID=1
INTERSECT
SELECT a2.Etuid
  FROM TableA a2
  INNER JOIN TableB b2 ON (a2.Tuid=b2.Tuid)
  WHERE b2.FID=2;
```

Outputs

```
ETUID
E1
E2
E3
```

[Online demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9da6e0/8)
(Please be noted that due to SQLFiddle's convention and my laziness I have to use double quote for column names; This may not be the case in your real code)

[Oracle document on `INTERSECT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries004.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an aternative:

```
select
Etuid
from
(
 select
 TableA.Etuid, TableB.FID, 1 cnt
 from
 TableA
 join TableB on TableA.Tuid = TableB.Tuid
 where TableB.FID in (1,2)
 group by TableA.Etuid, TableB.FID
) data
group by Etuid having sum(cnt) = 2;
```

[And here is a fiddle for it.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b8a9/1)

I added additional data for E4 so that it have 2 rows matched but both with `FID =1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select a.Etuid from TableA a inner join TableB b on a.Tuid=b.Tuid 
   where b.Fid in (1,2) group by a.Etuid having count(*)>=2 order by etuid;
```